# How to know if distribution of probabilities is symmetrical?

Tags: probability

A game involves spinning three spinners. The score for the game is the median of the three numbers which the spinners land on.

[image]

Complete the theoretical probability distribution for S, the score of the game.

[image]

I was able to find the probability of 1, which is 0.156 (5/32), and the probability for 4 must be the same as 1. What I don't understand is how to get the probabilities for 2 and 3. The answer scheme states that distribution must be symmetrical, meaning 2 and 3's probabilities must be the same and can be found by doing 2x+0.156+0.156 = 1.

But how do we know that the probabilties for 2 and 3 are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median is 1 if the spinners show a permutation of any of these triples

- $(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4)$

The median is 4 if the spinners show a permutation of any of these triples

- $(4,4,4),(4,4,3),(4,4,2),(4,4,1)$

So by the obvious symmetry, the probabilities of obtaining 1 and of obtaining 4 are equal.

Also they are equal to $\tfrac{1}{4^3}(1+3\tbinom 31)$, that is $5/32$

---

The median is 2 if the spinners show a permutation of any of these triples:

- $(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,2,2), (2,2,2), (2,2,3), (2,2,4)$

The median is 3 if the spinners show a permutation of any of these triples:

- $(4,3,2), (4,3,1), (4,3,3), (3,3,3), (3,3,2), (3,3,1)$

So we have a 1:1 equally probable correspondence between results where the median is 2 and those where the median is 3.  [There are as many permutations for $(1,2,3)$ et cetera as there are for $(4,3,2)$ et cetera.]

Comment: But wouldn't triplets like 2, 1, 3 also be a possibility? I'm pretty sure you put them in order. In the answer scheme, one of the triplets for a score of 1 is 141 for example.

Comment: $(2,1,3)$ is a *permutation* of $(1,2,3)$.  There are exactly as many permutation of $(1,2,3)$ as there are of $(4,3,2)$.  (Which is why I listed the triples in corresponding order).  @ChristopherU'Ren

Comment: Thanks a lot . Where did you get the 1/4^3(1+3(3 1)) from? Is that from a formula?

Comment: @ChristopherU'Ren There are $4^3$ equiprobable outcomes in total.  The count of favour outcomes (for a median of 1) is 1 permutation of $(1,1,1)$ and $\tbinom 31$ permutations for each of $(1,1,x)$ for 3 values of $x$; and $\tbinom 31$ counts the ways to select which spinner has the non-1 result.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't really understand how you get the 1+3(3 1) bit. What do you mean by (3 1)  permutations for each of (1,1,x) for 3 values of x and how (3 1) counts the ways to select which spinner has non-1 result? I just don't really get the nCr part.

Comment: @ChristopherU'Ren $(1,1,1)$ has $1$ permutation.  $(1,1,2)$ has $\tbinom 31$ permutations: $(1,1,2), (1,2,1), (2,1,1)$. Likewise the other two patterns, $(1,1,3)$ and $(1,1,4)$, each have $\tbinom 31$ permutations. $$1+3\times\tbinom 3 1$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's making sense now. I read online that the n stands for the set size and r is the number of objects being taken at a time, but aren't we taking more than one object at a time? And is ncr or npr being used?

Comment: @ChristopherUren The set is of the *placements* for the results; which spinners the numbers show upon.  When rearranging $(1,1,2)$, *one* from *three* places is selected for the 2, then the 1 are placed in the remaining two positions.  So the count is using $^3\mathrm C_1$.

Comment: But shouldn't NPR be used as we're looking for all possible permutations?

Comment: @ChristopherUren $^n\mathrm P_r$ counts the permutations of $r$ items selected from a set of $n$ *distinct* items.  So, no, it is not applicable.

Comment: But why is NCR applicable?

Comment: The members of the triplets are not *distinct*. @ChristopherUren

Comment: Aren't 2,1,1. 1,2,1 etc considered permutations? So wouldn't that make the NCR invalid as they are permutations, not combinations? And what is meant by distinct?